# How to send delete request to a python server

Tags: javascript, python, html, request

I am working on the front-end of an application. I need to send a delete request from the html template to the server. The delete function works as follows:

```
def do_DELETE(self):
        if re.match(r'\/product\/\d+', self.path): # match "/product/{ID}"
            #send response code:
            self.send_response(200)
            #send headers:
            self.send_header("Content-type:", "application/json")
            # send a blank line to end headers:
            self.wfile.write("\n")
            #send response:
            db.delete(re.search(r'[^/]*$', self.path).group(0)), self.wfile
            return
```

I understand the url request will be, say, `/product/2`. However, I am more familiar with node style, for example:

```
<form id="delete-form" action="product/<%= product._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

I am not able to find they way in which this will be handled when sending the request to a python server.

How would I send a url to the delete request in the python server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be making a HTTP `DELETE` request to your server. You are making a `POST` request, and you have a handler for DELETE.

You should probably use JavaScript to make the DELETE request.

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("DELETE", "/product/2");
oReq.send();
```